# Applying L'Hopital on $\lim_{x\to1^+}\left( \frac{1}{\ln(x)} - \frac{1}{x - 1} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to apply L'Hopital's rule here:

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\left( \frac{1}{\ln(x)}  - \frac{1}{x - 1} \right)$$

The indeterminate form here is $\infty - \infty$, so I need to somehow shape this limit to have a quotient instead. My attempt:

$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)}  - \frac{1}{x - 1} = \frac{\frac{(x-1)-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}}{(x-1)}$$

This becomes

$$\frac{(x-1)-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)\cdot(x-1)}$$

That's

$$\frac{0^+-0^+}{0^+\cdot0^+}$$

Hmmmm... Does this become $\frac{0}{0}$? I am not sure.

To me, $0^+$ means "some very small number greater than $0$", but two $0^+$ don't necessarily refer to the same number... **or do they?** Because if they don't, then $0^+ - 0^+ \not= 0$.

The same goes for $0^+ \cdot 0^+$, they are numbers greater than $0$ so their product cannot be $0$.

What do you think? Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Just note that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ are finite, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$, so indeed in your notation "$0^+-0^+=0$" and "$0^+\cdot 0^+=0$", but you're abusing notation there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep using L'hopital's rule if you have indeterminate forms $\left( \frac{0}{0} \right)$

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\left( \frac{1}{\ln(x)}  - \frac{1}{x - 1} \right)=\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{(x-1)-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)(x-1)}\right)$$
Using L'hopital as we have indeterminate form
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{(x-1)-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)(x-1)}\right)=\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{1-\frac1x}{\frac{(x-1)}{x}+\ln(x)}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{x-1}{x-1+x\ln(x)}\right)$$
Still indeterminate type so use L'hopital again
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{x-1}{x-1+x\ln(x)}\right)=\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{1}{2+\ln(x)}\right)$$
$$=\color{blue}{\fbox{0.5}}$$

So altogether L'hopital was used twice.

Comment: So $0^+ - 0^+$ is indeed $0$? And $0^+ \cdot 0^+$ is also $0$? I always thought that $0^+$ meant a number greater than $0$.

Comment: @ Zol Tun Kul The notation $0^+$ means _approach_ zero from above

Answer (score 4):

It is *much* simpler to use *Taylor polynomials at order* $2$.

Set $x=1+h$. The 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\ln(x)}  - \frac{1}{x - 1}&=\frac{x-1-\ln x}{(x - 1)\ln(x)}=\frac{h-\ln(1+h)}{h\ln(1+h)}=\frac{h-\bigl(h-\frac12h^2+o(h^2)\bigr)}{h\bigl(h+o(h\bigr)}\\
&=\frac{\frac12h^2+o(h^2)}{h^2+o(h^2)}=\frac{\frac12+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to\frac12.
\end{align*}

Comment: Well, it's good to know I can do this, but I suspect I'm not supposed to know / use this yet. Do you know if $0^+ - 0^+ = 0$? Or if $0^+ \cdot 0^+ = 0$?

Comment: These are not indeterminate forms. What'is indeterminates is $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ or $0\cdot\infty$ and a few others.

Comment: @Bernard Very impressive method (+1)

Answer (score 2):

We know $\lim_{x\to 1^+}((x-1)-\ln (x))=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\ln(x)(x-1)=0$, because if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ are finite, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$.

So we can apply L'Hopital's rule on

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{(x-1)-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{x-1}{x}+\ln(x)},$$

which is again of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ for similar reasons, so we can apply L'Hopital's rule again:

$$=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{1^2}}{\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you make a single fraction, you get
$$
\frac{x-1-\ln x}{(x-1)\ln x}
$$
Both the numerator and the denominator are continuous at $1$, so this limit is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. No need to consider signs, at this point.

You can avoid long applications of l'Hôpital with a simple observation:
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{x-1-\ln x}{(x-1)\ln x}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t\ln(1+t)}
$$
with the substitution $x-1=t$. Now you can rewrite the last limit as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t^2}\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)}
$$
and you should know that the second fraction has limit $1$; so we have
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1-\dfrac{1}{1+t}}{2t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t}{2t(1+t)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: very nice idea (+1)